# Sum values in the range based on if condition and for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I have 3 columns of data (I present a subset for ease of understanding). The first column shows label number, 2nd column the quanatities along label number, and 3rd the price.

I want to sum the price in for labels in columns 3 but only if Quantity in column 2 is >= 1, otherwise do nothing.

Data:

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

In the outcome, the Price in 3rd column is summed out of all values for Label1 and assigned to each label If Quantity in column 2 is >=1. For all the others, the price does not change because quantity is 0.

I am getting the mismatch for the ranges used. I am not sure if I should use arrays:

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim rngLabel As Range
Dim rngQuantity As Range
Dim rngAmount As Range

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

With ws1

    Set rngLabel = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
    Set rngQuantity = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2))
    Set rngAmount = .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3))

    For Each cell In rngLabel.Cells
        For Each cell2 In rngAmount.Cells
            If rngQuantity.Value >= 1 Then
            cell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngAmount)
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are built-in functions that can help you.

```
sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    With ws1
        with .range(.cells(3, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).offset(0, 1))
            .columns(4).cells.formular1c1 = "=if(rc[-2]>0, sumifs(c[-1], c[-3], rc[-3]), rc[-1])"
            .columns(3).cells = .columns(4).cells.value
            .columns(4).cells.clear
        end with
    end with

end sub
```

BTW, your range objects were being set all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet. You were missing the `.end(xlup)` at the end.